# Given a full name variable how to return back first name + last inital w JS only

Tags: javascript, regex

given a JS variable like:

```
var n = James Bond;
var n = James Earl Bond;
var n = James;
```

How can I return the first name plus last initial? While account for ignoring the middle name and the possibility of their only being a first name? Anyone solve this elegantly before?

Thanks

Comment: Names are incredibly complicated. Any solution you come up with is not going to work for 100% of names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function formatName(name)
{
    var newName;

    name = name.split(' ');
    newName = name.shift();

    if ( name.length ) newName += ' ' + name.pop()[0] + '.';

    return newName;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/68JVS/

Comment: +1 Although the accounting for there only being a first name is a bit interesting... but the OP didn't specify how to handle that case so it's not your fault.

Comment: @PaulP.R.O. for first name only, display the first name only and don't break :)

Comment: This solution would supply an odd output if only a first name. Would be in the format 'James .' as opposed to 'James'

Comment: @all - Updated with better handling of first name only.

Comment: aww, if you keep the original code and change one line to `name = name[0] + ' ' + ((name.length>1) ? name.pop()[0] + '.' : '');` that will do it

Comment: @CrayonViolent - Sure, but I wanted the code to be a bit more readable ;-)

Comment: @CrayonViolent - BTW, no need for `(name.length>1)`, `(name.length ? name.pop()[0] + '.' : '')` works just fine.

Comment: Seems declaring variables is soooo passé.

Answer (score 0):

```
var names=n.split(' ');

var newname=names[0];

if (names.length>1) {
    names.reverse();
    var newname+=' '+names[0].substr(0,1)+'.';
}
```

Returns 'James' if only one name, 'James B.' if a sirname. Ignores middle names, while accounting for no last name supplied.

Answer (score 0):

```
var name_comps = name.split(' ');
var first_name = name_comps[0];
var last_init = '';
if(name_comps.length >0){
    var last_init =  name_comps[name_comps.length -1].charAt(0);
}

var userName = first_name +  (last_init ? ' ' + last_init : '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use some regexp like that:

```
var formattedName = name.replace(/([^ ]+).*([A-Z])[^ ]*$/,"$1 $2.");
```

However for personal experience deal with name / surname as a whole string it causes a lot of problem, because there is no rule for naming, especially when you have a worldwide users case scenario.